# Correct return type hints with TaggedOutputs

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a `DoFn`, where I return a regular and a tagged output:

```py
class Foo(DoFn):
    UNPARSABLE_TAG = "unparseable_events"

    def process(
        self, element: Tuple[str, date]
    ) -> Iterable[Union[Event, str]]:
        ev, d = element
        if ev == "1":
            yield Event(ev)
        else:
            yield TaggedOutput(self.UNPARSABLE_TAG, ev)
```

Runtime type checking seems to expect a return hint that encompasses both regular and tagged output types.

While this is doable, when consuming both `PCollections` you then need to add a "decorator hack" to later get to correct types again:

```py
    valid, invalid = ... | ParDo(Foo()).with_outputs(Foo.UNPARSABLE_TAG, main="main")
    valid | Map(_beamDecoratorHack)
    ...

def _beamDecoratorHack(
    ev: Union[Event, str]
) -> Event:
    assert isinstance(ev, Event)
    return ev
```

This seems sluggish. Is there a way of not needing the hack?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand Union correctly, it lets you explicitly select types from inside the union.

For example:

```
def func() -> Union[int, str]:
    return "123"


# Type safe (although clearly wrong)
a: int = func()

# Not type-safe (although passable for some downstream usages)
a: list = func()
```

So for your example, I think this should work:

```
    valid: PCollection[Event], invalid = ... | ParDo(Foo())
    valid | ...
```

Comment: It is a bit more complicated for Beam since it inspects types at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The method `process` is annotated as returning an iterable `Union[Event, str]` - is this correct? From the code, I would assume that this should actually be `Union[Event, TaggedOutput]`.

Comment: Even if it were `TaggedOutput`, the problem that main result of `with_outputs` would be a Union instead of `Event` persists.